# Make an array of strings of the names saying whether or not they can go to The Matrix (Under the age of 18)

Tags: javascript, arrays

Make an array of strings of the names saying whether or not they can go to The Matrix (Under the age of 18)

```
console.log(makeStrings([
    {
        name: "Angelina Jolie",
        age: 80
    },
    {
        name: "Eric Jones",
        age: 2
    },
    {
        name: "Paris Hilton",
        age: 5
    },
    {
        name: "Kayne West",
        age: 16
    },
    {
        name: "Bob Ziroll",
        age: 100
    }
])); 
// ["Angelina Jolie can go to The Matrix", 
// "Eric Jones is under age!!", 
// "Paris Hilton is under age!!", 
// "Kayne West is under age!!", 
// "Bob Ziroll can go to The Matrix"]`
```

```js
console.log(makeStrings([
    {
        name: "Angelina Jolie",
        age: 80
    },
    {
        name: "Eric Jones",
        age: 2
    },
    {
        name: "Paris Hilton",
        age: 5
    },
    {
        name: "Kayne West",
        age: 16
    },
    {
        name: "Bob Ziroll",
        age: 100
    }
])); 

function makeStrings(arr){
return arr.map((x) => x.age < 18) ? arr.map((x) => x.name + " can go to The Matrix ") :       arr.map((x) => x.name + " is underage!!"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a second `map()`, when you start with a ternary operator (x.age < 18), you can return 2 strings, one for true and one for false.

Then by using a structure like

```
arr.map((x) => x.name + ((condition) ? 'true string' : 'false string'))
```

we start by adding the name, with the desired suffix.

```js
console.log(makeStrings([
    {
        name: "Angelina Jolie",
        age: 80
    },
    {
        name: "Eric Jones",
        age: 2
    },
    {
        name: "Paris Hilton",
        age: 5
    },
    {
        name: "Kayne West",
        age: 16
    },
    {
        name: "Bob Ziroll",
        age: 100
    }
])); 

function makeStrings(arr){
    return arr.map((x) => x.name + ((x.age < 18) ? " is underage!!" : " can go to The Matrix " )); 
}
```